# Python - Regular Expression to find dates in list

Tags: python, mysql, regex, datetime

While looping through a csv I'm attempting to normalize dates for a MySQL load (yyyy-mm-dd).  I've attempted to search for items that contain two forward slashes, but I've found that's not unique enough to identify a date. Can this be accomplished with a regular expression and looking for items that match a pattern?  Any input would be greatly appreciated.

example input:

```
['1','2','01/02/2015','3','4','1-05-2015','5','Anot/her Ex/ample','6']
```

example output:

```
['1','2','2015-01-02','3','4','2015-01-05','5','Anot/her Ex/ample','6']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the order of the fields. You can use datetime.strptime:

```
from datetime import datetime

l =  ['1','2','01/02/2015','3','4','1-05-2015','5','Another Ex/ample','6']

out = []

for ele in l:
    try:
        out.append(datetime.strptime(ele,"%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))    
    except ValueError:
        out.append(ele)

print(out)
```

I have no idea how you expect `'1-05-2015'` to become `'2015-01-05'` as you are only considering forward slashes for dates:

If you have multiple patterns to test:

```
out = []

for ele in l:
    for patt in ["%d/%m/%Y","%d-%m-%Y"]:
        try:
            p1 = datetime.strptime(ele,patt).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            if p1:
                out.append(p1)
                break
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
    else:
        out.append(ele)

print(out)
['1', '2', '2015-01-02', '3', '4', '2015-01-05', '5', 'Anot/her Ex/ample', '6']
```

You can also filter on length and only try to parse the correct length strings:

```
for ele in l:
    ln = len(ele)
    if 7 <= ln > 10:
        out.append(ele)
        continue
    for patt in ["%d/%m/%Y", "%d-%m-%Y"]:
        try:
            p1 = datetime.strptime(ele,patt).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            if p1:
                out.append(p1)
                break
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
    else:
        out.append(ele)
```

A regex is potentially going to match a lot more than just dates so unless you are 100 percent certain you should at least try casting what the regex returns to a datetime object before adding.

Comment: Hi Padraic - Unfortunately the order varies otherwise this would have been the ideal solution.

Comment: @user3582260, how does the regex work  for `'1-05-2015'`? Also a regex will fail for invalid dates

Comment: The regex would match `'102/02/123445/3232'` and numerous other strings so you would want to be sure you are only matching exactly what you should be

Comment: Thank you for following up.  After further review I found that I was too quick to rule this option out.  So far it appears strptime is performing very well.  As Martin has point out I have having difficulty converting the date '04/31/2001'

Comment: If you can have day/month/year and month/day/year you would have to account for all those possibilities but then you have problem. What should 1/1/2015 be?

Answer (score 3):

```
re.sub(r"(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)",r"\3-\1-\2",test_Str)
```

This should do it for you.

```
x= ['1','2','01/02/2015','3','4','1-05-2015','5','Anot/her Ex/ample','6']
print [re.sub(r"(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)",r"\3-\1-\2",i) for i in x ]
```

Comment: Thank you VKS!  We are very close!  Now I just need to append a zero in the event the month or day is only one digit.  For example, the date 1-05-2015 is currently displayed as 2015-1-05.  I would like it to display 2015-01-05.

Answer (score 1):

I feel @PadraicCunningham's solution would seem the most resilient, and it can easily be extended as follows to cater for the other case:

```
from datetime import datetime

l =  ['1','2','01/02/2015','3','4','1-05-2015','5','Another Ex/ample','6']

out = []

for ele in l:

    try:
        out.append(datetime.strptime(ele,"%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) 
        continue
    except ValueError:
        pass

    try:
        out.append(datetime.strptime(ele,"%m-%d-%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) 
    except ValueError:
        out.append(ele)

print(out)
```

This would now print out:

```
['1', '2', '2015-01-02', '3', '4', '2015-01-05', '5', 'Another Ex/ample', '6']
```

You should also consider the following test cases. These would result in no changes being made.

```
l = ['40/05/2015', '13/01/2000', '04/31/2001']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try code below:

```
import re

elements = ['1','2','01/02/2015','3','4','1-05-2015','5','Anot/her Ex/ample','6']
for element in elements:
    matches = re.match(r"(\d{1,2})[\/-](\d{1,2})[\/-](\d{4})", element)
    if (matches is not None):
        print '{:0>2}-{:1>2}-{:2}'.format(matches.group(1), matches.group(2), matches.group(3))
```